# How i can fix js import auto-hide problem in vs code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, import, prettier

Firstly, I imported something from another module in js:

```
import cloneDeep  from './node_modules/lodash-es/cloneDeep.js'
```

But when I am not using this `cloneDeep` in my code and save my script file, then VS Code automatically hides that line.

**Before Save**

[image: Before Save]

**After Save**

[image: After Save]

Comment: Are you using `eslint` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vcode settings.json

```json
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": false
  },
}
```

Comment: But I have a confusion. can this do any problem with the auto-import feature?

Answer (score 0):

try instead of `import cloneDeep from './node_modules/lodash-es/cloneDeep.js`

this: `import cloneDeep from 'lodash-es/cloneDeep.js`

you don't need to specify node_modules absolute path and if it's es6 import you need to add an entry in package.json:

```
"type": "module"
```

are you running it in NodeJs?

edit: if the code editor deleting it then it must be from a linter/extension causing it. Probably because you set the variable as global. either check the extension config or disable it or wrap the variable declaration in a function

Comment: No man, I am just trying on browser.